# Ways to bypass maybe 'breaks' do not span range of x?

Tags: r, histogram

Using the PlantGrowth built-in dataset in R, I am trying to make a histogram with the bins starting at 3.4 and incrementing by 0.4. The range of values in the dataset is [3.59, 6.31].

When I run `seq(3.4, 6.31, 0.4)`, I get:

```r
[1] 3.4 3.8 4.2 4.6 5.0 5.4 5.8 6.2
```

So, I see that the issue is that the maximum value is left out of the created bins.
Is there a way for me to say the number of bins is equal to the length of `seq(3.4, 6.31, 0.4)` plus 1? Or would it be better to add 0.4 to the maximum value so that the last value is included? Would either of those make the scatterplot incorrect?

[image: Picture of Histogram]

Above is an image of a histogram I made using my second idea. How do I get the x-axis numbers to reflect the values of the bin edges?

Comment: Are you using `cut`, then yoou can specify `breaks = c(seq(3.4, max(PlantGrowth$weight), 0.4), Inf)`

Answer (score 3):

Add `0.4` to the `to=` argument as well:

```r
S <- seq(3.4, 6.31, 0.4)
table(cut(PlantGrowth$weight, S), useNA = "always")
# (3.4,3.8] (3.8,4.2] (4.2,4.6]   (4.6,5]   (5,5.4] (5.4,5.8] (5.8,6.2]      <NA> 
#         1         3         4         5         8         4         4         1
```

That one `<NA>` is your problem-row.

Fixed:

```r
S <- seq(3.4, 6.31 + 0.4, 0.4)
table(cut(PlantGrowth$weight, S), useNA = "always")
# (3.4,3.8] (3.8,4.2] (4.2,4.6]   (4.6,5]   (5,5.4] (5.4,5.8] (5.8,6.2] (6.2,6.6]      <NA> 
#         1         3         4         5         8         4         4         1         0
```